# Как создавать переменную с заранее неизвестным именем

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

У меня есть класс Person

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
```

Я хочу создавать объекты класса так, чтобы они назывались по признаку self.name.

Т.е, к примеру, в псевдокоде это будет выглядеть так:

```
имя_человека = Person(имя_человека, пол)
```

Спасибо!

Comment: почитайте о словарях (dictionary) и о том как их применять в Python...

Comment: Вы так **хотите**? Или уверены, что какая-то задача так решается? Вопрос возник, потому что это выглядит очень нездоровым кодом.

Comment: Что вас смущает? Я хочу создавать объекты класса, которые будут называться по своему имени, вот и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если переменная создаётся в глобальной области видимости:

```
name = 'Иван'
globals().update({name: Person(name, 'male')})
# в глобальной области видимости теперь есть переменная с именем Иван, содержащий объект класса Person
```

Если переменная создаётся в локальной области видимости (внутри функции):

```
def someFunction(name='Иван'):
    locals().update({name: Person(name, 'male')})
    # в области видимости функции someFunction теперь есть переменная с именем Иван, содержащий объект класса Person
```

Если переменная создаётся внутри объекта класса:

```
a = SomeClass()
name = 'Иван'
a.__dict__.update({name: Person(name, 'male')})
# в объекте a теперь есть атрибут с именем Иван, содержащий объект класса Person
```

Comment: я получил ошибку длины имени ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required

Comment: @maroonkr какое имя вы попытались создать?

Comment: имя "Jana", я беру его из строчки внешнего файла

Comment: @maroonkr исправил ответ. Это уже технически опечатки, связанные с тем, что ответ из головы писал, не проверяя. Разумеется, ключ и значения словаря разделяются двоеточием, а не запятой.

Comment: Setattr правильней